# Reading response from Node JS Server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on a program where a specific Java file will be compiled at the Server side and if there is any error in compiling, I will capture the error information and send it back to the client side. However, I have tried many ways to read the JSON Object but to no avail.

So my question is why was I not able to read the error string sent by the server at the client side? I am current using **res.data.err** to read my error response.

**Server Side Code**

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');
exports.compileTest = function(req,res){

console.log(req.body.data.fileName);
var file = req.body.data.fileName;
var output = "";
 output = cmd.get(
    'javac solutionTest/'+file,
    function(err, data, stderr){

       if (err) {
           console.log(err);

           res.json({ state : 0 ,err});
        }
        else
             res.json({ state : 1});
    }
    );

}
```

**Client Side Code**

```
 $scope.compileSol = function(){
 $http.post('/testRun', { data : { fileName : $scope.solutionFileName.name} 
   }).then(function(res){
      if(res.data.state==0){
            alert(res.data.err);

      }
        }).catch(function(error){
    });
    }
```

Below is the error I wanted to send over to the web browser

[image]

Comment: You're sending `{state:0, err: ...}`, why would you expect to magically receive it as `{data: {state: 0, err: ...}}`? Remove the `data.` in `res.data.state`. Strongly recommend looking for the help pages for your browser's dev tools so you can look at the response, etc. Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: I added the `err` part behind the `{state}` - `res.json({ state : 0 ,err});` , shouldn't the `err` be sent together?

Comment: That's not my point (I've fixed the comment). It's the `data` part. What do you think is adding that extra object layer?

Comment: I've tried `res.err` but it is not working either. If `res.data.state` was able to be resolved(to a 0 which is a correct response from the server), why is the `res.data.err` not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake lies in assume `err` is the exact error output by the server.

Solution is to convert it to String and then send it over.

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');


exports.compileTest = function(req,res){

console.log(req.body.data.fileName);
var file = req.body.data.fileName;
var output = "";
 output = cmd.get(
    'javac solutionTest/'+file,
    function(err, data, stderr){

       if (err) {
           console.log(err);

       //added this line
       err = err.toString();

           res.json({ state : 0 ,err:err});

        }
        else
             res.json({ state : 1});
      }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `err` variable that you are sending from your server is a JSON object that has for key: `err`. If not, you can consider modifying it, the way I do below.

```js
  if (err) {
               console.log(err);

               res.json({ state : 0 ,err: err});
            }
            else
                 res.json({ state : 1});
        }
```

The object response on your client side should have the same form as how you sent it. In the way you are sending it from your server, it should be this way you can access it client side:

```js
if(res.state==0){
            alert(res.err);

      }
        }).catch(function(error){
    });
```

Comment: `res.json({ state : 0, err});` is modern JavaScript for `res.json({ state : 0, err: err});`, any vaguely-recent version of Node will support it. If it weren't supported, the OP wouldn't get the symptom they get; they'd get a syntax error.

Comment: @edkeveked Your answer gave me insight on my error, the `err` at the server-side was actually not a proper JSON Object. I had to use `err.toString()` method to convert it first and send over. I was then able to retrieve the error message.

I don't know about the convention but res.err still gives me `undefined` while res.data.err was able to resolve the response Object.